# Parse.com into jsonstring and back

Tags: c#, json, parse-platform, unity-game-engine

I am using PushWoosh to send custom data and wants to be able to send a ParseObject from one user to another. As far as I can see is this only possible if I first convert the ParseObject into an jsonstring and then on retrieval convert it back into an ParseObject.

I have tried with newtonsoft, miniJson and simple json but with no luck.

First of all... Can this be achieved and if yes... how?

```
ParseObject test = new ParseObject("jsontest");

test["gameid"] = "12345";
test["player"] = "hanson";

string parsetoJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(test); 
Debug.Log ("ParseJson: "+parsetoJson);
//Returns: ParseJson: [{"Key":"gameid","Value":"12345"},{"Key":"player","Value":"hanson"}]

ParseObject test2 = new ParseObject("jsontest");

test2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ParseObject>(parsetoJson);
Debug.Log ("ParseBack: "+test2.Get<string>("gameid"));
```

This gives this error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type `object' to`Parse.ParseObject'. An
>   explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Hoping for help in this matter and thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Seems like you need `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ParseObject>(parsetoJson);`

Comment: I changed it and now I get this error: Exception: Cannot create and populate list type Parse.ParseObject.

Comment: Is ParseObject a class you wrote?  Paste that in.  (because your 'new' consturctor call shows some arguments needed... there may be a way, but I don't think json.net can easily call constructors when you parse your json, this needs to be a dumb class)

Answer (score 0):

There may be other ways to do this, but the json.net way we use is:

```
string json = @"{
  'Name': 'Bad Boys',
  'ReleaseDate': '1995-4-7T00:00:00',
  'Genres': [
    'Action',
    'Comedy'
  ]
}";

Movie m = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Movie>(json);
```

You of course need to define the class you are deserializing locally as well, so something like:

```
public class Movie {
  public string Name { set; get; }
  public DateTime ReleaseDate { set; get; }
  public List<string> Genres { set; get; }
}
```

Long story short, define what you are serializing as a proper class and it'll work.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example for what you need to add to fix the sample you provided. You basically just need to create a class structured after the expected structure of the json.

```
using UnityEngine;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class JsonThings : MonoBehaviour
{
    public class ParseObject
    {       
        [JsonProperty]
        public int gameId;

        [JsonProperty]
        public string player;

        public ParseObject(string name)
        {

        }
    }

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () 
    {
        ParseObject test = new ParseObject("jsontest");
        test.gameId = 12345;
        test.player = "hanson";

        string parsetoJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(test);
        Debug.Log("ParseJson: " + parsetoJson);
        //Returns: ParseJson: [{"Key":"gameid","Value":"12345"},{"Key":"player","Value":"hanson"}]

        ParseObject test2 = new ParseObject("jsontest");

        test2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ParseObject>(parsetoJson);
        Debug.Log("ParseBack: " + test2.gameId);    
    }
}
```